# how to publish github repo which includes react project?

Tags: reactjs, github

Basically I have a webiste which is one folder which includes 2folders(client(react) and server(node and so on). I can't host my website cuz github need an index html file in the primary folder. What can I do?? . sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use github pages and it requires index.html at root, you need to either move reactjs part to root or split to 2ndary repo.

p.s. you could use aws to host static react app on s3 over aws cdn and configure as you want it but that approach will require some time to understand aws.

Comment: I dont think I can move the root. Can u elaborate more?

Comment: if your app's index.html is at `/client/index.html` make it `/index.html` as required by docs or use different hosting provider. Either update current repo or just create separate for react app.